# how to close created div by clicking outside of it?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a div that is created on a button pressed and I'm trying to have it deleted by clicking outside of it but it takes the original button press as clicking outside and immediately closes the div.

```
closediv();

    }

function closediv() {

    document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        const maindiv = document.getElementById('div3');
        let targetElement = evt.target;

        do {
            if (targetElement == maindiv.childNodes[1]) {
                return;
            }

            targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;

        } while (targetElement);

        var viewpost = maindiv.childNodes[1];

        viewpost.parentNode.removeChild(viewpost);
    });


}
```

Comment: the trick is to create a backdrop div that will take 100% height and 100% width, then put that "created" dive on top ... all you need now, is hook the backdrop div "click" event... or implement [jquery-outside-events](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-outside-events)

Answer (score 0):

In your button click handler, you could use

```
theButton.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  // rest of the code

});
```

and the click event [would not propagate to the parent containers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: I tried adding evt.stopPropagation(); but it didn't change anything

Comment: @zonzoan can you create a Snippet or JSFiddle so we can try and debug into...

Answer (score 0):

---

just add a click event on body to close your div and then add prevent default into your div to block closing action when user click on your div

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
  //close your div here
 })
document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
   evt.preventDefault()
   // your code
}
```